# count number of certain value occurances in a string

Tags: java, string, count

I have a string which contains my mail details such as

```
GitHub   Sat Jun 01 13:32:02 IST 2013
eBay   Mon Jun 03 17:37:40 IST 2013
YouTube   Tue Jun 04 00:18:50 IST 2013
YouTube   Sat Jun 08 01:20:47 IST 2013
eBay   Sat Jun 08 13:19:22 IST 2013
eBay   Sat Jun 08 13:17:53 IST 2013
eBay   Mon Jun 10 15:43:01 IST 2013
YouTube   Mon Jun 10 15:47:02 IST 2013
eBay   Wed Jun 12 11:10:15 IST 2013
eBay   Wed Jun 12 19:25:50 IST 2013
eBay   Thu Jun 13 17:22:14 IST 2013
eBay   Thu Jun 13 18:09:18 IST 2013
Clark University  Thu Jun 13 19:30:09 IST 2013
```

is there any way to get number of times eBay ,Youtube or anything has occured so that i can have a number of mails received from a particular person??

Comment: Is this really the whole string? Ie, there are newlines in it?

Comment: can I solve this problem using hashmap?? key:eBay Value:Mon Jun .. and count same keys..

Comment: Look at my answer. And please also answer my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using String tokenizer and match the value of first token.

If eBay is always going to be the first word then, you can use startsWith() method of String class.

Comment: there can be anything instead of eBay

Comment: and if the word changes its position you are going to change the code??

Comment: @chaosguru & all, This is just an approach. Implementation may differ according to the requirements. If there are multiple names, we can create separate lists for these names and add the string in corresponding list.

Comment: can I solve this problem using hashmap?? key:eBay Value:Mon Jun .. and count same keys..

Comment: HashMap allows unique keys. So, if you store the value with key eBay, it will overwrite previously saved value.
In this case, what you can do is, you can create Lists of values for a particular key (say eBay) and store that list in the HashMap against that key.

Answer (score 0):

try to use regular expressions with grouping of data.

Answer (score 0):

This solution supposes two things:

- names of days cannot appear in the first part;
- each entry is separated by a newline:

[extra line to fix SO bug with list items and code extracts]

```
private static final Set<String> DAYS = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
    "Mon ", "Tue ", "Wed ", "Thu ", "Fri ", "Sat ", "Sun "
));

public int nrMatches(final String mailList, final String sender)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int index;

    for (final String line: mailList.split("\r?\n"))
        for (final String day: DAYS) {
            index = line.indexOf(day);
            if (index == -1)
                continue;
            if (line.subString(0, index).trim().equals(sender))
                ret++;
        }

    return ret;
}
```